# Eloquent: Scope for Model where latest related Model meets permission

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a Model Products that has many of the Model Prices.
Every day there is a different price for the product.

Now I am trying to create a scope that gives me all products which latest price is between two values.

I tried this with a whereHas query:

```php
public function scopePriceBetween($query, ...$priceRange) {
  return $query->whereHas('price', function ($query) use ($priceRange) {
     $query->latestPrice()->whereBetween('price', $priceRange); 
  })
}
```

with the scope on the price model

```php
public function scopeLatestPrice($query) {
  return $query->latest('date')->limit(1);
}
```

But this will give me all the products where any price was between the range and not just the latest price.

Is there a way to do this with acceptable performance in eloquent or do I need to add a latest_price column to my product model?

Comment: How you are specifying latest price? do you have different price for the product? if yes how you are storying those?

Comment: dosent my answer satisfies  you? i think using scope for this situation is not a good idea

Comment: I am using a scope because I am using a package that makes filtering possible via query string which is then translated into a scope.

@PrafullaKumarSahu prices are their own model, they are storen in a table, prices for each day. So yes there are different prices for a product.

Comment: so i think you can implement last_price with one of methods i have mentioned. and use scope to query the last_price.

Comment: Would I create the temp table inside the scope?

Comment: do you want to always make query on last Prices?

Comment: This is used for a filter, so it needs to be chainable, I need to be able to do smth like Product::latestPriceBetween([100,200])->category('electronics'). And the query should return products with category electronics and where the latest price is between 100 and 200

Comment: i have updated my answer, i think its eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for later price you can use database temp column or you can use redis. but i recommend temp column.

### First Solution : Temporary Table

```
DB::statement("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE last_prices SELECT prices.* from prices join products on products.id=prices.product_id and prices.id=(select id from prices where prices.product_id=products.id and `prices`.`deleted_at` is null order by `id` desc limit 1);");
        $query = Product::select("products.*")
                 ->join("last_prices", "products.id", "last_prices.product_id");
```

in this example, every task has many jobs, you can query database to make a temporary table and fetch the `last_job` from `jobs`;

### Second Solution : Using Cache Server

DBMS temp table is fast, but you can gain performance by Cache server (for example redis).

you can store every product last price in cache server by product_id:

```
  public function getLastPriceAttribute(){
    
    //cache for an hour
    $p_id = $this->id;
    return  Cache::tags(['product'])->remember($this->id, 60*60, function () uses ($p_id) {
            return Price::where('product_id', $p_id)
                ->latest()
                ->first();
        });  
}
```

### The third solution:

if your price updates are daily and you haven't or don't want to use cache server you can make a database table named last_prices and update it daily with laravel schedule as follow:

in `App\Console\Kernel.php`  :

```
//suggestion has not tested
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            $updateValues = array();
            
            foreach( Product::all() as $product){
               array_push($updateValues , array(
                   "product_id" => product->id,
                   "price_value" => 
                   Price::where('product_id',$product->id)
                   ->latest()
                   ->first()->price_value;
                   ));
             }
        LastPrices::updateOrInsert($updateValues);
        })->dailyAt("05:30");        }
```

### UPDATE

for this:

```
Product::latestPriceBetween([100,200])->category('electronics');
```

you can make **Suggested Third Solution** to have Last_price Table.

and define scope with join, with this nice package : https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-eloquent-join

looks like something like this:

```
public function scopePriceBetween($query, ...$priceRange) {
  return $query->join("last_prices","last_prices.product_id","products.id")->whereBetween('last_prices.value', $priceRange);
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt I be creating a temporary table for every session? The logic is used in an api endpoint where I want to filter the prices in a certain range.